# Comparing date and time in bash

Tags: bash, datetime, if-statement

I want to compare two date&time variables:

`2016-01-21 17:15:06.614852743 +0300`

I am trying this:

```
MODDATE_INIT=$(stat -c %y /home/user/my_file)
if [ $(stat -c %y /home/user/my_file) -lt  $MODDATE_INIT ]; then cat my_file; fi"
```

I get error:

> bash: [: too many arguments
>   What I am doing wrong? Please, help me to fix my script.

Comment: You could also use the `-nt` comparator, that directly compares the file dates: `if [ file1 -nt file2 ] ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't quote your date string, so it's expanded by the shell and  appearing as

```
if [ $(stat ...) -lt 2016-01-21 17:15:06...]
       ^--arg 1          ^--arg 2   ^---arg 3???
```

to the `[` binary. The time component appears as an extra argument for the `-lt` test, hence "too many arguments".

Try

```
if [ $(stat -c %y /home/user/my_file) -lt  "$MODDATE_INIT" ]; then cat my_file; fi"
                                           ^-------------^
```

Note the extra quotes.

Comment: I know it's not 100% necessary in this case due to the format string used with stat but it still doesn't do any harm to quote the command substitution as well.

Comment: Or not need to quote anything and use `[[` as it is on bash.

Comment: Quoting is only one problem. The other is that you can't compare date strings using `-lt`

Comment: you can, as long as the string's formatted in most-significant-first ordering, and the timezones are the same.

Comment: `[ 2016 -lt "2017-10-12" ]` produces "bash: [: 2017-10-12: integer expression expected"